# I don't know why, when I Import materialize has problems Material UI REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Before, when i don't import materialize

[it's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dz5i.jpg)

[not import materialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Lsm.png)

After, when i imported materialize in index.js it broke my page like this

[the page have a container grid 12 column but i don't know how it do that, i just import not do any thing to want to have grid 12 column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3CqX.jpg)

[import materialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdHNE.png).

i hope every one can explain for me in this case :((

Comment: Less likely:  the materialize CSS has styles with the same class names that you use elsewhere in your code.  More likely:  the materialize CSS is applying global styling to the whole page which messes up your styles.  Something like `box-sizing` could be the culprit.  You’ll need to inspect the elements in dev tools to see what CSS is being applied and where it comes from.

Comment: @LindaPaiste omg T^T, you are right, I have a className coinciding with Material UI also has className that is "container".So, When I changed my className's name, it was active properly. Thank you for helping me answer questions, thank you very much. Have a good day.

Comment: Glad I could help!  With questions like these (just screenshots and no code text) there’s not enough information for anyone to give you a concrete answer.  But at least I’m able to point you in the right directions.

Answer (score 0):

**-- I have classname coinciding with Materialui, it is "container"--**

```
return (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map(player => (
        <div className="column" key={player.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={player.img}></img>
            <h3>{player.name}</h3>
            <p className="title">{player.club}</p>
            <Link to={`detail/${player.id}`}>
              <p><button>Detail</button></p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

    </div>
  )
```

[We can see that the container of Material UI is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXmiU.png)

**--After changing its name, it worked as I expected.--**

```
return (
    <div className="player__list">
      {data.map(player => (
        <div className="column" key={player.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={player.img}></img>
            <h3>{player.name}</h3>
            <p className="title">{player.club}</p>
            <Link to={`detail/${player.id}`}>
              <p><button>Detail</button></p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

    </div>
  )
```

[After I changed the name "container" it was active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pks0G.jpg)